Why isn't my link getting populated when using AMPscript
I'm using Salesforce Marketing Cloud and need to populate a link using AMPscript. For example, the link is
https://website.com/%%=v(@variable1)=%%/%%=v(@variable2)=%%/%%=v(@variable3)=%%

The link works when I preview the email. But when I test send, the link that opens is "https://website.com///" and all my variables are missing.
I have set the variables correctly as before this link was used, the previous link was
https://website.com?variable1=%%=v(@variable1)=%%&variable2=%%=v(@variable2)=%%&variable3=%%=v(@variable3)=%%

and it works.
Could it be because the link uses "/" instead of "=" which is somehow affecting how the AMPscript is working? Would you have any suggestions on how I can get the AMPscript to work? I don't think I can use the redirect link function as I have to feature the link 8 times with each time using different sets of variables according to the data extension.
Thanks in advance!
The link should be populated correctly when I click on it in my test send.

You should use the Concat function along with RedirectTo, to implement this properly. Resulting in following code:
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat("https://website.com/",@variable1,"/",@variable2,"/",@variable3))=%%">Hello link!</a>

